# Workspace does not build after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have two swift projects, `application` and `library`, where `library` is a dependency of `application`.  I have a `Podfile` configured as so;

```
workspace 'myworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target :library do
    project 'library/library.xcproject'
    pod 'GCDWebServer', '~> 3.0'
    target :application do
        project 'application/application.xcproject'
    end
end
```

After running `pod install` successfully, I open `myworkspace` in Xcode, and find `application` as the currently selected scheme.  Immediately building results in failure, due to;

> No such module 'library'

To solve this I need to change the current scheme to `library`, build, then switch the scheme back to `application` and it will successfully build.

Questions;

1. Is this expected, or a bug in xcode and/or CocoaPods, or have I configured something incorrectly?
2. Does this mean I need to separately build `library` anytime `library` source changes occur to reflect those changes in `application` builds?

Xcode 7.3, CocoaPods 1.0.1, [repo](https://github.com/staff0rd/podtest/tree/dc7109eec08e9c28e5b7258ccf978e455d632c31)

Answer (score 2):

Try do the followings:

> 1.Open the 'xxx.xcworkspace' file to run your project. Do not open 'xxx.xcodeproj' to run your project again.
>
> 2.Product->Clean->Run
>
> 3.Add all the pod targets to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' in Project -> General

Comment: Are these guesses? Naturally I had opened the workspace rather than the project, and the workspace (and projects) had never been built before, so why would a Clean be required?  Finally, shouldn't Cocoapods be taking care of the Linked Frameworks?

Comment: It is not a step guide. These issues may solve your problem. Actually add all the pod targets to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' is not required for every circumstance. You may have a Pods_xxx.framework linked to your project. This is the packaged dynamic framework cocoa pods build for you.

Comment: I appreciate you offering workarounds, but as per the question I am already able to tweak the output such that it builds, and rather I am asking whether such tweaking is a requirement of using Cocoapods or if something is incorrectly configured.