# Workspace includes missing files after pod install and successful build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have two swift projects, `application` and `library`, where `library` is a dependency of `application`.  I have a `Podfile` configured as so;

```
workspace 'myworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target :library do
    project 'library/library.xcproject'
    pod 'GCDWebServer', '~> 3.0'
    target :application do
        project 'application/application.xcproject'
    end
end
```

After running `pod install` successfully, and building ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755626/workspace-does-not-build-after-pod-install)), the workspace includes two missing files as seen in red in this screenshot;

[image]

Is this expected or is something wrong?

Xcode 7.3, Cocoapods 1.0.1, [repo](https://github.com/staff0rd/podtest/tree/dc7109eec08e9c28e5b7258ccf978e455d632c31)

Answer (score 2):

These warnings are not actual build warnings, but came from your SVN / GIT repository. It is true that the directories shown no longer exist. Please update your working copy to reflect those changes. Once you commit your working directory, the warning should go.

Please check following GitHub issue for discussion and solution to your problem.

[Github issue Link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3341)

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This problem often occurs in Xcode. Different things work for different situations, but restarting Xcode as well as building and running the project often fix the issue. Trying options along those lines will most often fix the issue.